# Can't use sudo when logging in through ssh

Tags: fedora, sudo, openssh

What is going wrong?  When I log in using ssh, I am unable to use `sudo`:

```
$ ssh localhost
Last login: Tue Jan  3 15:59:29 2017 from fd5e:fcf3:b885:10::175
[alan-sysop@volcano ~]$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for alan-sysop: 
alan-sysop is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[alan-sysop@volcano ~]$ id -a
uid=1000(alan-sysop) gid=1000(alan-sysop) groups=1000(alan-sysop),1002(sysnote),1003(sshlogin) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

`sshd_config` is edited with the following lines at the start:

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK

# No brute force attacks
PasswordAuthentication no

# No root user (unless given command enabled in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys)
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only

# SSH users must be whitelisted by admin
AllowGroups sshlogin root

# No fearmongering about missing DNS ("POSSIBLE BREAK IN ATTEMPT")
UseDNS no

# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

`sudoers` has the default line from Fedora

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

My user is in group wheel

```
$ id -a
uid=1000(alan-sysop) gid=1000(alan-sysop) groups=1000(alan-sysop),10(wheel),1002(sysnote) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

openssh-server-7.3p1-7.fc25.x86_64
sudo-1.8.18p1-1.fc25.x86_64
```

Comment: yeah, I'll delete it. It's obsolete now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Latest update:** This issue occurred on one old machine, which went on to report media errors ("bad sectors") on the root filesystem.  The drive may well be dying, so I've evacuated my files.  Other Fedora 25 machines did not show this issue.

Lessons:

- I look forward to having a filesystem with data checksums at some point :).
- Always remember there's a difference between your current groups (`id -a`) and groups applied on next login (`id -a "$USER"`).

**Update**: I have submitted this to the Fedora bug tracker: [Opening Gnome Users immediately removes me from group wheel (sudo access)!](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1409874)

---

My user is *not* in group `wheel` anymore:

```
$ id alan-sysop
uid=1000(alan-sysop) gid=1000(alan-sysop) groups=1000(alan-sysop),1002(sysnote),1003(sshlogin)
```

Sometime during my session my user was removed from group `wheel`.

I made sure to re-add myself (before I ended my session!)

```
sudo usermod -a -G wheel alan-sysop
```

During the session I had run `sudo usermod -a -G sshlogin alan-sysop`.  I had not fallen into the common trap of forgetting `-a` in the `usermod` command.  For one, I can see that I passed `-a`.  Also, I remained a member of group `sysnote`; if I had forgotten `-a` then this would also have been removed.

This leaves one possibility:  I had also opened the Gnome Users settings pane.

Perhaps I entered my password o authenticate (to make changes to users) and then mis-clicked the "Standard" account type button without realizing it?

NOPE.  Opening the Gnome Users settings page and entering my password *is immediately removing my user from the wheel group!*  Sigh.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Comments added to the bug you filed.

Comment: Use `strace` to find out how actually it is doing that.